# When I define the optional params in angular ui router,it will get an error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to achieve in the angular-ui-router features optional parameters and default parameters, but do it in accordance with the document said, will always be an error, I do not know how to do, please help, I will be grateful to you

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
   <a ui-sref="main">go to main</a>
   <div ui-view></div>
</div>

var App = angular.module("myApp",["ui.router"]);

App.config(function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider.state("main",{
      url:"main/:name",
      template:"<div>I want to kick your ass, {{name}}</div>",
      params:{
         name:{value:"janry"}
      },
      controller:function($scope,$stateParams){
         $scope.name = $stateParams.name
      }
  })    
});
```

This is my demo on jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/janry_wang/p739U/7/

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to define a params object. Just do it like this:

```
 var App = angular.module("myApp",["ui.router"]);

    App.config(function($stateProvider){
        $stateProvider.state("main",{
            url:"main/:name",
            template:"<div>I want to kick your ass, {{name}}</div>",
            controller:function($scope,$state){
                $scope.name = $state.params.name
            }
        })    
    });
```

Comment: Because I do not want to incoming parameter to state and I want it auto pass the default params when I use ui-sref